# How to disable textboxs in radio button with Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

My function is

- If I choose the first (second or last) option, the rest option will be **disabled** and **reset as null** and all values in the selected option will be **enabled** as my Javascript below.
- Moreover, I would like to **disable textboxs** as the left-hand side below whenever the `taxi` option has been **selected**.

---

[image]

---

**<kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/bT79r/31/)</kbd>**

**HTML:**

```
<table>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="company_vehicle" />Company Vehicle</td>
</tr>
<tr class="set_width" id="company_vehicle">
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="checkbox" />Company Vehicle</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="hiring_vehicle" />Hiring Vehicle</td>
</tr>
<tr class="set_width" id="hiring_vehicle">
    <td>
        <input type="text" />
    </td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="car" />Car</td>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="abc" value="bus" />Bus</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>
        <input type="radio" name="vehicle" value="taxi" />Taxi</td>
</tr>
<tr class="set_width" id="taxi">
<td>
        <input type="checkbox" />Taxi</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**Javascript:**

```
var rbt_vehicle = $("input[name=vehicle]");

$(rbt_vehicle).on('change', function (e) {
var valueSelected = this.value;

$('#' + valueSelected).find(':text').prop('disabled', false).val('').removeClass('readonly').closest('tr').siblings('tr.set_width').find(':text').prop('disabled', true).addClass('readonly');
$('#' + valueSelected).find(':checkbox,:radio').prop('disabled', false).closest('tr').siblings('tr.set_width').find(':checkbox,:radio').prop('disabled', true);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your current function, you can actually remove a lot of the current code and just do the following:

```
var rbt_vehicle = $("input[name=vehicle]");

$(rbt_vehicle).on('change', function (e) {
    var valueSelected = this.value;

    // your other code here ...

    $('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', valueSelected === 'taxi');

});
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/bT79r/35/)**

Comment: I've edited my thread and I would like to keep my current JS code and then add _"the disabled textbox"_ code whenever the `taxi` has been selected...

Comment: @PMay1903 well in that case, just add the following line to your existing function: `$('input[type="text"]').prop('disabled', valueSelected === 'taxi');` and that should do it

Comment: Thank you very much. That works well now :-) I am wondering that I should put your code above or below my code?

Comment: @PMay1903 that depends on what you aim to do. If the rest of your code does not depend on the textboxes being disabled or enabled, you can put it wherever you like, if you have logic that is dependent on the disabled state of your textboxes then you'll need to put this line above that code.

Comment: I got it now. Thank you again for your explanation!

Answer (score 2):

do like this:

```
$('input.rdo').click(function(){
if(this.id == 'rdoTaxi')
{
    $('.textbox').prop('disabled',true);
}
    else
    {
        $('.textbox').prop('disabled',false);
    }

});
```

[**Fiddle DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/xD5q5/)

Comment: Thank you for you code but I would like to add these into my own current function with Javascript...

Comment: @wvandaal what you mean by that?

Comment: @EhsanSajjad it's a common idiom, basically in this case it means that you can show the OP a better way, but you can't make him **see** that it's the better way

Comment: I've edited my thread and I would like to keep my current JS code and then add _"the disabled textbox"_ code whenever the `taxi` has been selected...